# Javascript : Filter result from keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have the below object:

```
var colors = {
    key1:"Red",
    key2:"Blue",
    key3:"Green",
    key4:"Black"
}
```

I also have this array of keys:

```
var keys = ["key1","key3","key4"]
```

I want to fetch the corresponding colors from `colors`. For that, I have written code -

```
keys.map((key)=>{
    var color= colors.filter(x=>x==key);
});
```

But I am getting error here  -

```
colors.filter is not a function
```

Comment: Are you using color.filter or colors?

Comment: colors.filter. It was typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract each of the keys, `map` is the correct option but you just need to fetch the corresponding value from `colors`:

```js
var colors=
{
  key1:"Red",
  key2:"Blue",
  key3:"Green",
  key4:"Black"
};
var keys = ["key1", "key3", "key4"];

const result = keys.map(key => colors[key]);

console.log(result);
```

Note that if a key doesn't exist, the value output is `undefined`. To remove `undefined` values append `.filter(Boolean)` at the end (thanks [Roko C. Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan)):

```
const result = keys.map(key => colors[key]).filter(Boolean);
```

Your issue was you were trying to run `filter` on an object. `filter` is not a method on objects, instead it's an array. If you want to use `filter`, one option is to use `Object.entries` like so (but the solution above is far simpler).

```js
var colors=
{
  key1:"Red",
  key2:"Blue",
  key3:"Green",
  key4:"Black"
};
var keys = ["key1", "key3", "key4"];

const result = Object.entries(colors).filter(([key, color]) => keys.includes(key)).map(([, color]) => color);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: As a PS: add also `.filter(Boolean);` to the end of the script, to filter out possible `undefined` ... since you're using `.map()` ...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, I'll include that as well - although I did mention `undefined` was a possible output, always good to have a way to remove them. (I really like `filter(Boolean` by the way, super clean - thank you!)

Comment: const result = keys.map(key => colors[key]);  This did my job. Thank You.

Comment: Also, instead of `Object.entries.filter().map()` use just `.reduce()` like: `keys.reduce((a, k) => (colors[k]&&a.push(colors[k]), a), []);`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, but I wanted to show a `filter` solution for OP since that's what they were using initially. Not sure why I'd use `reduce` in this case, to be honest... since I'm already dealing with an array I could just use `map`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
var colors = {
  key1:"Red",
  key2:"Blue",
  key3:"Green",
  key4:"Black"
}
    
var keys = ["key1","key3","key4"]
    
let a = keys.map((key)=>{
  return colors[Object.keys(colors).filter(x=>x==key)];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const colors = {
  key1:"Red",
  key2:"Blue",
  key3:"Green",
  key4:"Black"
};
const keys = ["key1", "key3", "key4", "key99"];

const result = keys.reduce((a, k) => (colors[k]&&a.push(colors[k]), a), []);

console.log(result)
```

notice that the `"key99"` will not be included in the `result` Array